# Socket.io и ООП. Насколько такой подход правильный?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Практикуюсь в Node.js и понадобились socket-ы
Насколько правильным будет их реализация в ООП? В гугле не нашел примеров написания сокетов в классах.
Весь проект будет написан с применением ООП и хочется сделать отдельный класс с событиями и вызывать события в контроллерах, но не знаю имеет ли такой подход право на жизнь.

Answer (score -1):

Это две разные вещи ООП это по сути набор функций, которые называются методами так как обладают инкапсуляцией  и прочим. То есть ООП подход это оформление кода по большей части, а сокеты это технология, которая будет реализована в методах класса.
Методы это теже контролеры только в более узком смысле. Тут либо в фреймворке есть варианты либо ваша реализвция. Тут нет одного паатерна или шаблона из ооп тут связка шаблонов рекомендую https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns